# Asp.Net api com xml IsCancellationRequested

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

Tenho uma api que aceita a requisição post com json e xml para PedidoCompra, para os casos em que recebo o xml está ocorrendo um cancelamento da requisição de forma anômala,
ou seja, alguns entram na api e outros caem como requisição cancelada.

```
public static void ConfigureWebApi(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Remove o XML
    var formatters = config.Formatters;
    var xml = formatters.XmlFormatter;
    xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
    xml.Indent = true;
    xml.SetSerializer<Application.API.ViewModels.v1.Processo.ProcessoViewModel>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(Application.API.ViewModels.v1.Processo.ProcessoViewModel)));
    xml.SetSerializer<Application.API.ViewModels.v2.Processo.ProcessoViewModel>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(Application.API.ViewModels.v2.Processo.ProcessoViewModel)));

    xml.SetSerializer<Application.API.ViewModels.v1.Invoice.InvoiceViewModel>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(Application.API.ViewModels.v1.Invoice.InvoiceViewModel)));
    xml.SetSerializer<Application.API.ViewModels.v2.Invoice.InvoiceViewModel>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(Application.API.ViewModels.v2.Invoice.InvoiceViewModel)));

    xml.SetSerializer<Application.API.ViewModels.v2.PedidoCompra.PedidoCompraViewModel>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(Application.API.ViewModels.v2.PedidoCompra.PedidoCompraViewModel)));

    xml.SetSerializer<ListaDespesasViewModel>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListaDespesasViewModel)));
    xml.SetSerializer<ListaNumerarioViewModel>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListaNumerarioViewModel)));
    xml.SetSerializer<TesteViewModel>(new XmlSerializer(typeof(TesteViewModel)));


    // Modifica a identação
    var jsonSettings = formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
    jsonSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    jsonSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    // Modifica a serialização
    formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

no log a unica mensagem que obtenho no erro é 2021-02-11 14:27:52.2552

> Info Portal.API.Handlers.ErrorHandlingFilter.OnException -
> ErrorHandlingFilter Message: **The operation was canceled**.
> 2021-02-11 14:27:52.2552 Info
> Portal.API.Handlers.ErrorHandlingFilter.OnException -
> ErrorHandlingFilter InnerException:  2021-02-11 14:27:52.2552 Info
> Portal.API.Handlers.ErrorHandlingFilter.OnException -
> ErrorHandlingFilter InnerException:  2021-02-11 14:27:52.2552 Error
> Portal.API.Handlers.ErrorHandlingFilter.OnException -
> ErrorHandlingFilter ExceptionLogger ->  2021-02-11 14:27:52.2552 Error
> Portal.API.Handlers.ErrorHandlingFilter.OnException
>
> - Message      : ErrorHandlingFilter ExceptionLogger ->
> - ErrorSource  :
> - ErrorClass   :
> - ErrorMethod  :
> - ErrorMessage :
> - ErrorLineNumber   :
> - InnerErrorMessage :
> - StackErrorMessage :

Um detalhe enviando a requisição via swagger este problema não ocorre, mas se o cliente envia do ERP isso ocorre, a requisição não está sendo cancelada após o envio e sim durante o processamento da requisição, porém não exibe erro ou log do motivo.

Alguém já teve este problema ou faz ideia do que possa ocasionar esse problema?

Comment: Você tem como verificar os XMLs que o ERP está enviando? Tanto no caso de sucesso quanto no de falha? Usou essas evidências para debugar o seu código?

Comment: sim, se pego o xml que recebo e aplico via swagger dá sucesso, já tentei debugar mas o problema não ocorre.

Comment: verifiquei também as alternativas que encontrei neste link: [https://qastack.com.br/programming](https://qastack.com.br/programming/22157596/asp-net-web-api-operationcanceledexception-when-browser-cancels-the-request), agora vou testar a ultima da lista

Answer (score 0):

Verificando o log do IIS teremos as seguintes informações:
sc-status   sc-substatus    sc-win32-status time-taken
500         64              124887

sc-win32-status 64 significa "O nome da rede especificado não está mais disponível".
Depois que o IIS enviou a resposta final ao cliente, normalmente ele aguarda uma mensagem ACK do client.
Neste caso o client redefiniu a conexão após o envio para liberar o socket ao envez de esperar a resposta.